# Google Cloud SQL migration to second generation caused spike in Read/Write operations

Tags: mysql, sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I had to migrate from Google Cloud first generation SQL to second generation SQL (MySQL 5.6) instance.

When I check the performance charts in the SQL dashboard in Google cloud, what strikes me is the huge spike in "read/write operations", since the moment of migration.

What is more interesting is "MySQL queries" chart, remains the same, same number of queries on average, no difference since the migration.

Can anyone tell me what can make read/write operations significantly higher while the number of queries remain the same ?

I attach screenshots of "MySQL queries" vs "Read/write operations".

[image]

[image]

Comment: is high availability enabled on your instance?

Comment: @JorgeHDZ Yes it is.

Comment: I think that's caused by HA tasks, you could try to disable the HA instance and check if reads and writes decrease

Comment: @JorgeHDZ This didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this issue is related with the product, maybe is good idea [file a case with customer support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat) to check the issue on a deeper way.